# creating a for loop to calculate a sum for a certain year

Tags: r, for-loop

I wrote some data into a CSV- this should be a shareable link. If it says no access, then just in general terms is greatly appreciated. https://drive.google.com/a/rice.edu/file/d/0B-O6tTyIMPyaNUNtQlJGVkNRcGs/view?usp=sharing

I have a data set with over 220,000 entries. What I am trying to do, without writing 50+ lines of code is:

There is a category called `fyear`, ranging from 1980 for 2014. For each year, I want to take the sum of the column called "revenue" for that year, and then divide it by the number of entries for that year.

Without a loop, it would be- for example the year 1980

```
n80<- subset(returns, fyear=="1980")
sum(n80$returns) / length(n80)
```

and it would return the value I want- but I don't want to go through and do this 44 times. So, I need to make a loop of some sort I assume. All I can come up with is

```
returns=NULL
for (i in 1:fyear) {
year.returns[i]= sum(returns$return)/ length(?)
```

How to I reference the length of the number of entries for each fiscal year?

Reading up on `apply`/`sapply` etc now to see if I can figure out how to do it that way.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with dplyr

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(fyear) %>%
  summarize(mean_returns = mean(returns) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Since fyear is a numeric value its easy to iterate over the range:

```
for(i in 1980:2014){
  x<- subset(returns, fyear==i)
  sum(x$returns) / length(x)
}
```

In your original code you have 1980 in quote indicating it's a character if this is the case you could use `fyear == as.character(i)`

You could also vectorize the solution using `sapply`

Answer (score 1):

One simple approach I can think of is using `unique`. Use `years <- unique(returns$fyear)` to get a vector containing all the years. And then you can loop through values in `years` vector and do the calculation you've mentioned in the question.

It will take care of any missing year as well.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(data)`), grouped by 'fyear', we get the `mean` of 'returns'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, list(mean_returns = mean(returns)) , by = fyear]
```